# Why is my jquery refresh creating a separate write out of my div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, refresh

I am trying to refresh the contents of my 'stats' div every two seconds, using jquery.  In the div it begins by writing out the contents of stats.php (which contains values from a database).  I want the div to reload that page every two seconds, in order to display the live values of the database table.

The original code all works.  Stats.php writes out perfectly how I want it to, but if I change the stats in the database and wait a few seconds, it never updates on the website to reflect those changes, unless I manually refresh the page (which I'm trying to avoid).

I have gone through so many forums and solutions and I can't seem to get any of coding examples to work.

[EDIT: The code now mostly works!! However, instead of simply refreshing the div, it creates a totally separate write out above my table, so I see the original div and then a secondary div. Updated code and picture below]

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lands Between</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css2.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
              setInterval(function() {
                $('#stats').load('php/stats.php');
              }, 2000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navtop">
            <div class="header">
                <h1 style="color: white; font-family: 'Blackadder ITC', 'Playbill', 'Poor Richard'; text-shadow: 1px 1px #403d39;">
                    Lands Between
                </h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="content">
            <table align="center" class="main-table" style="padding-right: 5px">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4">
                        <div id="chad">
                            <a href="php/charstats.php" target="screen">
                                <img src="graphics/Chad100pxHeadon.png"></div>
                            </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" colspan="2" style="padding-right: 10px">
                        <strong>Chad - Level <?php echo $lvl; ?></strong> | 
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <div id="stats">
                    <?php include 'php/stats.php'; ?>
                </div>
                
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <iframe name="screen" src="locations/<?php echo $location; ?>.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
            <?php include 'php/actionbuttons.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my stats.php page:

```html
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
include_once 'functGeneral.php';
    
    //user's specific id is stored in the cookie
    $id = $_COOKIE["user"];
    
    //pull users character stats from database using id
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $charInfo = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    //store the stats to variables
    $hp = $charInfo['hp'];  $hpmax = $charInfo['hpmax'];
    $mp = $charInfo['mp'];  $mpmax = $charInfo['mpmax'];
    $xp = $charInfo['xp'];  $lvl = $charInfo['lvl'];
    $str = $charInfo['str'];  $spd = $charInfo['spd'];
    $armor = $charInfo['armor'];    $weapon = $charInfo['weapon'];
    
    //get percentages for stat bar widths
    //variables are used at bottom in javascript code
    $hpbar = ($hp / $hpmax) * 100;
    $mpbar = ($mp / $mpmax) * 100;
    $xpmax = getmaxXP($lvl);
    $xpbar = ($xp / $xpmax) * 100;
    
?>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div id="hp" class="w3-container w3-round-xlarge w3-red" style="max-height: 30px; height: 30px; width: 100%; text-shadow: 1px 1px #403d39;">
                <span style="position: absolute;">HP: <?php echo $hp; ?>/<?php echo $hpmax; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div id="mp" class="w3-container w3-round-xlarge w3-blue" style="max-height: 30px; height: 30px; width: 100%; text-shadow: 1px 1px #403d39;">
                <span style="position: absolute;">MP: <?php echo $mp; ?>/<?php echo $mpmax; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div id="xp" class="w3-container w3-round-xlarge w3-yellow" style="max-height: 30px; height: 30px; width: 100%; text-shadow: 1px 1px #403d39;">
                <span style="position: absolute;"><font color="white">XP: <?php echo $xp; ?>/<?php echo $xpmax; ?></font></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var hpwidth = <?php echo $hpbar ?>;
    var mpwidth = <?php echo $mpbar ?>;
    var xpwidth = <?php echo $xpbar ?>;
    
    document.getElementById("hp").style.width = hpwidth + "%";
    document.getElementById("mp").style.width = mpwidth + "%";
    document.getElementById("xp").style.width = xpwidth + "%";

</script>
```

Comment: It's probably a caching issue; the browser thinks it's loading a URL with a GET whose content it has already seen, so it doesn't bother to load it again. If you change the `.load()` call to add a dummy parameter with a unique value, the browser will bypass the cache because it's a new unrecognized URL.

Comment: try  to change that `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: that's an interesting idea...I'm fairly new to jquery, how could I go about adding a dummy parameter?

Comment: `$(function() { setInterval(function() { $('#stats').load('php/stats.php?rnd='+new Date().getTime()); }, 2000); });`

Comment: have you a live version?

Comment: @simone-rossaini landsbetween.kayforte.com is the website, but you'd have to create an account in order to access the page and you wouldn't be able to adjust the database to see live changes

Comment: no was just for see console dev. can you check error ?

Comment: the code is working now, but it is not writing over the original div contents, just adding to it.....so now I have two stat bars

Comment: Add a separate tbody to hold the stats instead of a div which is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load jQuery over https intead of http (not the problem but still)
2. Do not link to w3schools stylesheets (not the problem but still)
3. Your HTML is invalid. You likely want your stats to be a tbody instead of an invalid DIV
4. Cache buster:

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#stats').load('php/stats.php?rnd=' + new Date().getTime());
  }, 2000);
});
```

Table suggestion:

```html
<table align="center" class="main-table" style="padding-right: 5px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" id="chad">
        <a href="php/charstats.php" target="screen">
          <img src="graphics/Chad100pxHeadon.png">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td align="right" colspan="2" style="padding-right: 10px">
        <strong>Chad - Level <?php echo $lvl; ?></strong> |
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="stats">
    <?php include 'php/stats.php'; ?>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <iframe name="screen" src="locations/<?php echo $location; ?>.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried each of these suggestions and it's still not working.

Comment: this is working! However, the code is creating a separate stat bar, which appears completely above my table, instead of just updating the div in it's current location....basically I see my original write out of stats.php and a secondary write out which appears above my table.

Comment: @KatieScalf I cannot know what your code returns if you do not show an example

Comment: Your HTML is invalid anyway. Your div needs to be in a table cell or you will get content outside the table

Comment: @mplunjan stats.php includes the rest of the table. but I suppose that's not the best way to do it.

Comment: @mplunjan thank you for your help! everything is working, just need to tinker with the aesthetics a bit.